# AVAudioPlayer not playing sound when tap gesture recognizer pressed

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am creating a flashcard app.  Right now I am at the point where I can swipe left and right through each image.  Each image has a sound file associated with it.  When the image is clicked on, the sound file associated with it should play.  As of now I can swipe through the images, but no sound plays when i tap the image.  Code below.

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate  {



var imageIndex: Int = 0
@IBAction func home(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "home", sender: self)
}

@IBOutlet weak var imgPhoto: UIImageView!


let itemList:[Card] = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "alligator")!, soundUrl: "Alligator.m4a"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "apple")!, soundUrl: "Apple.m4a"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "ball")!, soundUrl: "Ball.m4a")
]



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer:)))
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imgPhoto.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    imgPhoto.image = (itemList[0] ).image

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    imgPhoto.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    leftSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Swiped(gesture:)))
    rightSwipe.cancelsTouchesInView = false

    leftSwipe.direction = .left
    rightSwipe.direction = .right


    view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)
    view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

}

   @IBAction func imageTapped(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("hhh")
    itemList[imageIndex].playSound()
    // Your action
}

func Swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {

        switch swipeGesture.direction {

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right :
            print("User swiped right")

            // decrease index first

            imageIndex -= 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex < 0 {

                imageIndex = itemList.count - 1

            }

            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image

        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left:
            print("User swiped Left")
            // increase index first

            imageIndex += 1

            // check if index is in range

            if imageIndex > itemList.count - 1 {

                imageIndex = 0

            }



            imgPhoto.image = itemList[imageIndex].image
        default:


            break //stops the code/codes nothing.
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then I have another class which has the AVAudioPlayer code and lays out the definition of each "Card"(code below).

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

class Card: NSObject
{
var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String


init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
}
func playSound()
{
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    print("play")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

The code compiles without error, but no sound is played.  The program does print a line when I tap the screen but I do not have any line printed from the play sound function which must mean that that part of the code is not being executed. I have put the var player : AVAudioPlayer? outside of the class as recommended but still no luck. I have already added the AVAudioPlayer framework so that is not the problem either.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i post your answer make sure you have given right extension and it is not require in your card constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in your extension you have given wrong extension at

```
 guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a")
```

and also extension not required here

```
Card(image: UIImage(named: "alligator")!, soundUrl: "Alligator"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "apple")!, soundUrl: "Apple"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "ball")!, soundUrl: "Ball")
```

Change extension with your file extension **.mp4**

Comment: Hello, I tried that but still no luck :(  i dont think it is calling the play sound function

Comment: put the log at first line(before guard statement) of play function i am sure it will print log

Comment: you are right, it does print the line.  Im not sure what the problem could be

Comment: I am dam sure... what is your file extension and where actually it is located

Comment: I posted the screenshot

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at my latest question? I'm just trying to finish up what we started a few days ago.  Thank you

Comment: It show me old question that was solved
Last we solved sound player problem  right

Comment: I'm trying to get first list and second list to add together

Comment: @AnthonyRubin i cant see the question at that link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422655/adding-multiple-arrays-to-form-one-final-array-debug-swift-xcode?noredirect=1#comment77958110_45422655

Comment: Sorry I posted the new link

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove filename extension as:

```
let itemList:[Card] = [
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "alligator")!, soundUrl: "Alligator"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "apple")!, soundUrl: "Apple"),
    Card(image: UIImage(named: "ball")!, soundUrl: "Ball")
]
```

because your are adding extension in `func playSound()` function as

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }

func playSound() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }

    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

so it's add double extension to your filename which is not available in your bundle.

**NOTE:** Make sure your filename and extension is same as your bundle file name.
The file needs to be properly imported (Project Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources).

[image: Add folder]

[image: Folders look as]

Comment: I did that and it still does not play the sound.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: please check file needs to be properly imported (Project Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources).

Comment: I added two screenshots to the question for you to see

Comment: Please delete app ready sounds folder and add again as (Project Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources)

Comment: check updates answer,  so the added folder colour as yellow colour.

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my new question? I am trying to finish off what I started in this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45488593/compounding-multiple-arrays-debugging-xcode-swift

Comment: it would be much appreciated.  I can offer you some of my reputation in exchange for an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue is causing because of NSDefaultRunLoopMode  in which both event are running simultaneously. I was facing an issue with this NSDefaultRunLoopMode when i was updating lable for time in milliseconds . on opening keyboard its was not updating in that time only. Then to solve that issue i run that timer in NSRunLoopCommonModes. I am not sure if it will work in your case but still sharing if it can help you in anyway..